How can I preset a dictionary so that it works in SwiftUI preview?
I am building a LazyVGrid from an array located in a SwiftUI Dictionary.
The dictionary is built when the app is initialized:
var choices : Dictionary <String, [Int]> = [
    "firstRound" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
]

And the part of the code where I use it to build the grid is:
struct PickANumber: View {
   ...
   VStack {
   LazyVGrid(columns: columns ) {
      ForEach(0..<(choices["firstRound"]!.count ), id: \.self) { index in
         Text("\(choices["firstRound"]![index])")
            .padding(.top, 10)
      }
     }
   }
}

#Preview {
    PickANumber()
}

My issue is that to work on the grid, I need to run the debugger so that the Dictionary is initialized and populated. So, I can't use the preview to help me edit the look and size of the grid.
Is there a way I can initialize the Dictionary within the Preview so that I can more easily work on the appearance of the grid?

Yes. Pass choices as a parameter to PickANumber

you should start with a model struct that is SwiftUI and ForEach compatible. It's kind of a waste of time to attempt to use Dictionary since it isn't compatible and you'll likely end up needing custom properties and logic in your struct anyway.
